# Crash startActivityForResult(intent,1);

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a problem in my android application, I have a hand page, I change my business with

```
startActivityForResult (intent, CODE_DE_MON_ACTIVITE).
```

It works, but then when I replace this page since the second activity with the same code but nothing works. The application crashes.
Knowing that I have all the activities in the Manifest.

Log:

```
06-28 13:09:47.765: D/AndroidRuntime(254): Shutting down VM
06-28 13:09:47.765: W/dalvikvm(254): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
06-28 13:09:47.765: E/AndroidRuntime(254): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
06-28 13:09:47.775: E/AndroidRuntime(254): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{referencehit.android/referencehit.android.AddTournamentActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-28 13:09:47.775: E/AndroidRuntime(254):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
06-28 13:09:47.775: E/AndroidRuntime(254):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
06-28 13:09:47.775: E/AndroidRuntime(254):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
06-28 13:09:47.775: E/AndroidRuntime(254):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
06-28 13:09:47.775: E/AndroidRuntime(254):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-28 13:09:47.775: E/AndroidRuntime(254):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-28 13:09:47.775: E/AndroidRuntime(254):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
06-28 13:09:47.775: E/AndroidRuntime(254):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-28 13:09:47.775: E/AndroidRuntime(254):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-28 13:09:47.775: E/AndroidRuntime(254):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
06-28 13:09:47.775: E/AndroidRuntime(254):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
06-28 13:09:47.775: E/AndroidRuntime(254):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-28 13:09:47.775: E/AndroidRuntime(254): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-28 13:09:47.775: E/AndroidRuntime(254):  at referencehit.android.AddTournamentActivity.onCreate(AddTournamentActivity.java:38)
06-28 13:09:47.775: E/AndroidRuntime(254):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-28 13:09:47.775: E/AndroidRuntime(254):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
06-28 13:09:47.775: E/AndroidRuntime(254):  ... 11 more
06-28 13:09:47.788: I/dalvikvm(254): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
06-28 1
3:09:47.788: E/dalvikvm(254): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
```

Have you an idea of ​​my problem?

Comment: see AddTournamentActivity.java line no. 38

Comment: NullPointerException in AddTournamentActivity at line no 38.

Comment: huge clues int the stacktrace

Comment: Well, it says in the error log: "Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at referencehit.android.AddTournamentActivity.onCreate(AddTournamentActivity.java:38)"

Comment: Had you putted <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 in your AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you actually assigned a value to the `Intent`? Simply coding `Intent intent;` will throw a `NullPointerException` when you call `startActivity(intent);` like the one you got. Alternately, have you added your second activity to the Manifest file? Android won't launch an Activity that isn't in its Manifest.

Comment: Yes, I have added all the activities in the Manifest. And for the Intent: Intent intent = new Intent(TournamentsActivity.this,AddTournamentActivity.class); |

Comment: Can you post your Manifest file as well as some more relevant code?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but I solved the problem with the question above.

Answer (score 1):

Add followin permission to ur AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

If u have forgotten to add it, then add it.

Comment: What is the code at Line Number **38** in your AddTournamentActivity.java file